# Riverpod stateNotifierProvider state is null

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, riverpod, flutter-state

Even after setting the state of Riverpod `stateNotifierProvider`, the state is null when used in the widget.

I have this provider

```
final imageNotifierProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<ImageNotifier, FilePickerResult?>(
        (ref) => ImageNotifier());

class ImageNotifier extends StateNotifier<FilePickerResult?> {
  ImageNotifier() : super(null);

  void addImage(FilePickerResult result) {
    state = result;
  }
}
```

I'm reading the state like this:
`final selectedImage = ref.watch(imageNotifierProvider);`

Inside an onpressed event I'm setting the state to `FilePickerResult` and also printing the state.

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    final image = await ref.read(externalFileFunctionsProvider).getSingleImage();
    if (image != null) {
      print("Image selected !!");
      ref.read(imageNotifierProvider.notifier).addImage(image);
      print(selectedImage);
    }
  },
  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
)
```

I am expecting the output after the onpress event something like:

```
Image selected !!
// some FilePickerResult
```

Instead I'm getting:

```
Image selected !!
null
```

###### This is the full code

```
final imageNotifierProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<ImageNotifier, FilePickerResult?>(
        (ref) => ImageNotifier());

class ImageNotifier extends StateNotifier<FilePickerResult?> {
  ImageNotifier() : super(null);

  void addImage(FilePickerResult result) {
    state = result;
  }
}

Future<void> addNewGroupChatDialog(
  BuildContext context,
  WidgetRef ref,
  String userId,
  List<GroupChatDetail?> chats,
) {
  TextEditingController groupNameController = TextEditingController();

  final firestoreChatFunctions = ref.watch(firestoreChatProvider);
  final selectedImage = ref.watch(imageNotifierProvider);

  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
        title: Text(selectedImage?.files.toString() ?? ""),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
            TextField(
              controller: groupNameController,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: "Group Name",
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5)),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
            if (selectedImage == null)
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 50,
                    backgroundImage:
                        AssetImage('assets/images/profile_placeholder.jpeg'),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final image = await ref
                          .read(externalFileFunctionsProvider)
                          .getSingleImage();
                      if (image != null) {
                        print("Image selected !!");
                        ref
                            .read(imageNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .addImage(image);
                        print(selectedImage);
                      }
                    },
                    iconSize: 50,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            if (selectedImage != null)
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50,
                backgroundImage:
                    FileImage(File(selectedImage!.files.first.path ?? "")),
              )
          ]),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child:
                Text('Cancel', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
              child: Text('Add', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium),
              onPressed: () {
                if (groupNameController.text == "") return;
                firestoreChatFunctions.addNewGroupChat(
                    result: selectedImage,
                    groupName: groupNameController.text,
                    uid: userId);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}

SnackBar errorSnackBar(String msg) {
  return SnackBar(content: Text(msg));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point is that your provider is disposed of because when the dialog is called, it is probably no longer tracked. You can verify this by adding it to your provider:

```dart
ref.onDispose((){print('Has been Disposed');});
```

To solve the problem:

1. you can remove the `.autoDispose` modifier
2. add this line

```dart
final selectedImage = ref.watch(imageNotifierProvider);
```

in the widget from which your `addNewGroupChatDialog` method is called. Thus, the provider will not be disposed of.

**Notes**:

1. Use `ref.read` instead of `ref.watch` in callbacks (your `addNewGroupChatDialog` is a callback):

```dart
  final firestoreChatFunctions = ref.read(firestoreChatProvider);
  final selectedImage = ref.read(imageNotifierProvider);
```

2. You created a `groupNameController` but did not provide a disposal method. Memory leak, hello?

```dart
TextEditingController groupNameController = TextEditingController();

// when groupNameController.dispose(); ?
```

You can pass your controller from the main widget (which has an overridden `dispose()` method, or use a statefull widget here in the dialog)

Comment: I removed the .autodispose and replaced ref.watch with ref.read in the callback, but still the state remains null after calling ref.read(imageNotifierProvider.notifier).addImage(image), but when I close the dialog and re-open the dialog, the state has the value previously set. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you! Mark this answer as correct, please, to help others.

Comment: It still doesn't re-builds the AlertDialog, I have to close and re-open it to see the change in state. But I found a solution, I'll post that.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but your answer does not address the original question asked...

Comment: I tried adding onDispose(), and found that the provider was not being disposed when dialog was shown, so that was not the problem.

Answer (score -1):

### Solved this by wrapping Dialog() with Consumer()

I don't know if this is the right way, but I solved it by wrapping the Alert dialog with a Consumer() and adding `final selectedImage = ref.watch(imageNotifierProvider)` under the consumer.

```
showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {

    // Used a consumer

      return Consumer(
          builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? child) {

     // Watching the provider
        final selectedImage = ref.watch(imageNotifierProvider);

        return AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
          ......... .. ..
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).