Why the state is not persistent over screens of stateNotifierProvider of riverpod in flutter?
I am trying to persist the state of a form globally but what i am getting is the default value when i am navigating to another screen in the same project?
i have found similar post here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76037798/riverpod-statenotifierprovider-state-is-null](Similar link here) but its different from my implementation the solution here is i am already using but still not working??
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cook_net/base_components/button/text_button.dart';
import 'package:cook_net/base_components/edit_text/edit_text_comp.dart';
import 'package:cook_net/network/models/posts/post_form_model.dart';
import 'package:cook_net/network/services/posts/create_post_service.dart';
import 'package:cook_net/network/state_management/post_form_state.dart';
import 'package:cook_net/screens/home/home_layout.dart';
import 'package:cook_net/utils/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:cook_net/utils/dimensions/full_screen_dim.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

final postFormProvider = StateNotifierProvider<PostFormNotifier, PostFormModel>(
    (ref) => PostFormNotifier());

class PostScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final String postType;
  const PostScreen({super.key, required this.postType});

  @override
  ConsumerState<PostScreen> createState() => _PostScreenState();
}

class _PostScreenState extends ConsumerState<PostScreen> {
  late XFile? file;
  final FocusNode _recipeNameFocus = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _postDescriptionFocus = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _postTagsFocus = FocusNode();
  late TextEditingController _recipeName;
  late TextEditingController _postDesc;
  late TextEditingController _postTags;
  late PostFormModel postForm;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _recipeNameFocus.addListener(handleRecipeNameFocus);
    _postDescriptionFocus.addListener(handlePostDescFocus);
    _postTagsFocus.addListener(handlePostTagsFocus);

    postForm = ref.read(postFormProvider);

    _recipeName = TextEditingController(text: postForm.recipeName);
    _postDesc = TextEditingController(text: postForm.description);
    _postTags = TextEditingController(text: postForm.tags.join(" "));

    file = ref.read(fileProvider);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _recipeName.dispose();
    _postDesc.dispose();
    _postTags.dispose();

    _recipeNameFocus.removeListener(handleRecipeNameFocus);
    _recipeNameFocus.dispose();
    _postDescriptionFocus.removeListener(handlePostDescFocus);
    _postDescriptionFocus.dispose();
    _postTagsFocus.removeListener(handlePostTagsFocus);
    _postTagsFocus.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void handlePostDescFocus() {
    if (!_postDescriptionFocus.hasFocus) {
      if (_postDesc.text == "") {
        return;
      }
      ref.read(postFormProvider.notifier).updatePostDescription(_postDesc.text);
    }
  }

  void handlePostTagsFocus() {
    if (!_postTagsFocus.hasFocus) {
      if (_postTags.text == "") {
        return;
      }
      ref.read(postFormProvider.notifier).updatePostTags(_postTags.text);
    }
  }

  void handleRecipeNameFocus() {
    if (!_recipeNameFocus.hasFocus) {
      if (_recipeName.text == "") {
        return;
      }
      ref.read(postFormProvider.notifier).updateRecipeName(_recipeName.text);
    }
  }

  void _uploadPost() async {
    await PostService().createPost(ref);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = CDimensions.getScreenWidth(context);
    double screenHeight = CDimensions.getScreenHeight(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            width: screenWidth,
            height: screenHeight * 0.92,
            color: primaryDlightbg,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: screenWidth,
                  height: 106,
                  // color: primaryDOrange,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        height: 70,
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: const CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                              "assets/images/cook_net_logo.png",
                            ),
                            radius: 25,
                          ),
                          title: Text(
                            "John_Doe01",
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              color: primaryDColor,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text(
                            "John Doe",
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              color: primaryDColor,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          trailing: const Icon(
                            Icons.more_vert,
                            color: primaryDColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        // color: primaryDOrange,
                        height: 36,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              const Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.bowlRice,
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 8,
                              ),
                              //2 Add a text editing field for the recipe name...
                              CEditText(
                                hinText: "Add recipe name..",
                                editTextHeight: 30,
                                editTextWidth: screenWidth * 0.7,
                                maxLines: 1,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: screenWidth,
                  height: screenHeight * 0.5,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  //2 make this image/video dynamic
                  child: Image.file(File(file!.path)),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: screenWidth,
                  height: 40,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          "add recipe",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: primaryDColor,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 17,
                          ),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            context.push("/recipe/add");
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.chevronRight,
                            size: 16,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: screenWidth,
                  height: 50,
                  // color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              icon: const Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.heart,
                                size: 24,
                              ),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              icon: const Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.comment,
                                size: 24,
                              ),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              icon: const Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.paperPlane,
                                size: 24,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: const Icon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.bookmark,
                            size: 24,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      //2 make this editable text field,..
                      CEditText(
                        hinText: "Add a post description..",
                        editTextHeight: 60,
                        editTextWidth: screenWidth,
                        maxLines: 2,
                      ),
                      CEditText(
                        hinText: "Add 4-5 tags..",
                        editTextHeight: 60,
                        editTextWidth: screenWidth,
                        maxLines: 2,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    CTextButton(
                      onPressed: () => context.pop(),
                      text: "Cancel",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    CTextButton(
                      onPressed: _uploadPost,
                      text: "Save",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Here i am manging the state>>
import 'package:cook_net/network/models/posts/post_form_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class PostFormNotifier extends StateNotifier<PostFormModel> {
  PostFormNotifier()
      : super(const PostFormModel(
          recipeName: "",
          description: "",
          tags: [],
        ));

  void updatePostDescription(String description) {
    state = state.copyWith(description: description);
  }

  void updateRecipeName(String name) {
    state = state.copyWith(recipeName: name);
  }

  void updatePostTags(String tags) {
    List<String> sTags = tags.split(' ');
    state = state.copyWith(tags: sTags);
  }

}

this is the modal for the postForm>>

import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'post_form_model.freezed.dart';
part 'post_form_model.g.dart';

@freezed
class PostFormModel with _$PostFormModel {
  const factory PostFormModel({
    required String recipeName,
    required String description,
    required List<String> tags,
  }) = _PostFormModel;

  factory PostFormModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PostFormModelFromJson(json);
}


please dont mark it similar post as i have already watched other solutions but there is slight change in mine so not working for me..

Are you using the same postFormProvider in other screens as well or do you have another provider defined in each screen?

Stop using StateNotifier.  In particular, Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

The documentation of riverpod discourages the use of StateNotifier, see migration from StateNotifier.
By default, the state is auto-disposed for example when navigating from one screen to another. To preserve state, riverpod offers the option keepAlive.
I noticed that you are already using code generation, so why not build your providers as well?
import 'package:cook_net/network/models/posts/post_form_model.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'post_form_notifier.g.dart';

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class PostFormNotifier extends _$PostFormNotifier{
  
  // Implement the method build: 
  @override
  PostFormModel build() {
    return const PostFormModel(
          recipeName: "",
          description: "",
          tags: [],
        );
  }

  void updatePostDescription(String description) {
    state = state.copyWith(description: description);
  }

  void updateRecipeName(String name) {
    state = state.copyWith(recipeName: name);
  }

  void updatePostTags(String tags) {
    List<String> sTags = tags.split(' ');
    state = state.copyWith(tags: sTags);
  }
}


For the required dependencies see: riverpod: getting started.
